# Mouse freezing when connected through USB hub

Tags: windows-10, usb, usb-hub

I do know already that the reason behind my mouse randomly freezing when connected through a USB hub is that the hub doesn't have its own power source.

I have two USB ports on my laptop. One I use for my external audio card which takes lots of power, and on the second USB port I connect a hub. To the hub I connect an optic mouse. Once I also connect an external hard drive to the hub, the mouse (sometimes) starts freezing and doesn't move smoothly.

The thing is: Around 50% of the time it does work fine, it's just that sometimes it freezes and it doesn't seem to be related to any usage patterns, just totally random.

My question: Is there any kind of settings that I can tweak or play around with so it doesn't freeze?
I tried to set my power mode to "best performance" but it didn't help

I'm using Windows 10 if it matters

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the USB hub of poor quality? Also make sure it is fully connected. Comments are not answers technically. They can be used to get information and to verify common issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it might be of poor quality, it's called Orico USB

Comment: Your harddrive may pull so much data or power that it blocks the rest. Try to see if the audio card works on the usb hub and switch the mouse and sound card. May work well. Also, you may get good results if the harddisk is connected directly to the laptop, and the mouse and soundcard connect through the hub.

Comment: I tried that too, I guess I'll have to buy a better hub...Thank you for your answer